# Do loop until the array will be empty of its elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

*I want to write a function what is sum the array max and min multiplies and return that value.*

```
arr = [12,6,10,26,3,24]
```

**For example:**

```
26*3 + 24*6 + 12*10 = 342
```

**I have the code like this:**

```
function minSum(arr) {
var i;
var Result=0;

for (i = arr.lenght; i >= 0, i-2) { // I need the first help here

    Result = Result + Math.max.apply(null,arr) * Math.min.apply(null,arr);

    var indexMax = arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null,arr));
    if(indexMax != -1) {   // remove the current max value from the array.
      arr.splice(indexMax, 1);
    }

    var indexMin = arr.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null,arr));
    if(indexMin != -1) {   // remove the current min value from the array.
      arr.splice(indexMin, 1);
    }

}

return;  // need the second help here
}
```

All code works so i need only to finish the loop part and the return statement. I want to do the loop until the array is empty ***I like to finish this way*****and other solutions are welcome too!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution tries to keep the spirit of the given function by using [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)/[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) for getting the values for the product.

It works by using the length of the array for iterating and uses two variables for `min` and `max` values. This prevents to use `Math.min` and `Math.max` again for getting the index for splicing.

At the end return `result` with [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```js
function minSum(array) {
    var result = 0,                            // variable with starting small letter
        min, max;                              // helpers for keeping the found values

    while (array.length) {                     // check against the length
        min = Math.min.apply(null, array);     // get min value
        max = Math.max.apply(null, array);     // get max value

        result += max * min;                   // update result

        array.splice(array.indexOf(min), 1);   // delete min value
        array.splice(array.indexOf(max), 1);   // delete max value
    }
    return result;                             // return the result
}

console.log(minSum([12, 6, 10, 26, 3, 24]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [12,6,10,26,3,24];
var newArr = arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){return b-a}), sum = 0;
while(newArr.length) sum += newArr.shift() * (newArr.pop() || 1);

console.log(sum);
```

**Explanation**

1. Sort the `newArr`, separating max/min numbers `[26, 24, 12,` `10, 6, 3]`

   ```
         [26, 24, 12, 10, 6, 3]
          ^                  ^
      arr.shift()    *     arr.pop()
   ```
2. Get first `arr.shift()` and last element `arr.pop()`, multiply
3. Sum all interactions

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the logic by sorting the array first.

```js
var arr = [12,6,10,26,3,24] ;

arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a-b;
});

var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
  result += arr[i]*arr[arr.length - i -1];
}


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the middle element is ignored when the length is uneven:

```js
const minMaxMultiply = (input) => {
  // Clone input
  const arr = [...input];
  
  // Sort
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  
  let result = 0;
  const len = arr.length;
  
  // Multiply
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(len / 2); i = i + 1) {
    // console.log(`${result} + ${arr[i]} * ${arr[len - i - 1]}`)
    result = result + arr[i] * arr[len - i - 1];
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(minMaxMultiply([4, 11, 8, 1, 6, 12, 20, 32, 7]));
console.log(minMaxMultiply([]));
console.log(minMaxMultiply([4]));
```